# google chrome extension : play youtube in background.html

Tags: google-chrome-extension, youtube-api

Was developing an extension where I can have the 'Play' button in 'popup.html' and wanted a way to play it from 'background.html' so that the video can play in the background even if the extension is not active.

Any clue guys or any other way out ?

Thank u :)

Comment: Did it work for you? I am trying a similar extension but could not get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embed youtube player into your background page and control it with [Youtube Player API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html).

Comment: Just FYI, it's no more the Javascript API but the [IFrame API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)